# Redirect from Django template to edit a specific user

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, admin

I'm trying to allow a link b/w a template `http://localhost:8000/userSettings/` and and an individual user account on the admin page (allow admin user the ability to change permissions) `http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/1/change/`

I'm trying to do it w/ an  tag within the template:

```
            <a target="_blank" href="{% url 'admin:auth_user_changelist' %}">link</a>
```

This works fine for directing to `http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/` , but I'm trying to get to `http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/1/change/`

I also tried

```
 <a target="_blank" href="{% url 'admin:auth_user_changelist' user.id %}">link</a>
```

but I get the error `Reverse for 'auth_user_changelist' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/auth/user/\\Z']`

Any idea how I can direct a user to the edit page of a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```html
<a target="_blank" href="{% url 'admin:auth_user_changelist' %}">link</a>
```

To this:

```html
<a target="_blank" href="{% url 'admin:auth_user_change' user.id %}">link</a>
```

(`changelist` -> `change`)